# Not able to mock a constructor´s property: ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined (Jest, Enzyme)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In my test file I am mounting a Component and one of the nested Components is making me troubles. This is the Component:

```
class CacheHandler extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      isLatestVersion: false,
      refreshCacheAndReload: () => {
        if (caches) {
          caches.keys().then((names) => {
            names.forEach((name) => {
              caches.delete(name);
            })
          });
        }
        window.location.reload(true);
      }
    };
     // ...some other code
  }
   
  render() {
    const { loading, isLatestVersion, refreshCacheAndReload } = this.state;
    return this.props.children({ loading, isLatestVersion, refreshCacheAndReload });
  }
}

CacheHandler.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default CacheHandler;
```

I do not know how properly mock the constructor's refreshCacheAndReload property that gives me grey hair. It would be totally ok if it just does not do anything in the mock, but it shoud be found during the mounting process. At the moment, when I run my test, I get because of that part *ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined*

This is what I tried inside of my test but failed (Error: "CacheHandler" is read-only.):

```
const fakeCacheHandler = jest.fn(() => ({
  constructor(props) {
    //super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      isLatestVersion: false,
      refreshCacheAndReload: () => { }
  }},
  render() {
    const { loading, isLatestVersion, refreshCacheAndReload } = this.state;
    return this.props.children({ loading, isLatestVersion, refreshCacheAndReload });
  }
  
}))     
CacheHandler = fakeCacheHandler;
```

I also tried to define the property directly in test but without success:

```
Object.defineProperty(CacheHandler, 'CacheHandler', {
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    loading: false,
    isLatestVersion: false,
    refreshCacheAndReload: () => {}
  }))
})
```

I also tried to mock the whole module in the test like this:

```
jest.mock('../../components/utilities/CacheHandler', function() {  
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {       
       return {           
        refreshCacheAndReload: () => {},
        render: () => {this.props.children({ loading:false, isLatestVersion:false, refreshCacheAndReload })},        
}})
});
```

but still not successful.

jest.spyOn fails as well(Cannot spy the refreshCacheAndReload property because it is not a function; undefined given instead)

```
const fakeHandler = new CacheHandler();

const methodSpy = jest.spyOn(fakeHandler, "refreshCacheAndReload"); 
methodSpy.mockImplementation(() => {
  console.log('test!');
})
```

This is how the test itself look like now:

```
  it('renders MembersList', async () => {
    const Component = withMemory(AdminAppCore, ROUTE_ADMIN_MEMBERS);
    const result = mount(
      <MockProvider stores={{ memberStore, programStore }}>
        <Component />
      </MockProvider>
      
    );
    console.log(result.debug());
    await waitForState(result, state => state.loading === false);
    expect(result.find(MembersList).length).toBe(1);
    result.unmount();
  });
```

I tried to mock the constructor of child element inside the test like this, but if failed(TypeError: this.props.children is not a function):

```
it('renders MembersList', async () => {
    const Component = withMemory(AdminAppCore, ROUTE_ADMIN_MEMBERS);
      const mockrefreshCacheAndReload = jest.fn(() => ({}));
      const component = shallow(<CacheHandler/>);
      component.setState({refreshCacheAndReload: mockrefreshCacheAndReload}); 
    const result = mount(
      <MockProvider stores={{ memberStore, programStore }}>
        <Component />
      </MockProvider>      
    );
    console.log(result.debug());
    await waitForState(result, state => state.loading === false);
    expect(result.find(MembersList).length).toBe(1);
    result.unmount();
  });
```

So I am mounting the AdminAppCore, and inside of the AdminAppCore is the nested component  that causes troubles.

Can anyone please explain me how can I mock the refreshCacheAndReload state inside of the nested Component constructor?

Comment: Have you tried using jest spy?
It goes something like this 
const methodSpy = jest.spy(classInstance, "methodNameInString");
methodSpy.mockImplementation..

Comment: Yes I did, but I get the error TypeError: jest.spy is not a function :(
I tried it this way:
const methodSpy = jest.spy(CacheHandler, "refreshCacheAndReload"); 
methodSpy.mockImplementation(() => {
  //***** implementation****
})

Comment: Sorry my bad, the function is called jest.spyOn and not jest.spy
Also you may need an instance of CacheHandler  and not the class itself for it to work.

Comment: Can I create the instance also within the test itself? I tried but it was not working. I always get the error Cannot spy the refreshCacheAndReload property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that we ignored the fact that the method is part of the state.
And somehow to test this component, you will need to load this component using jest/enzyme, then create a mock function for refreshCacheAndReload, and then attach it to the state. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot post this in the comments, so please try this.

```
const mockrefreshCacheAndReload = jest.fn(() => ({}));

it('tests the method', () => {
    const component = shallow(<CacheHandler/>);
    component.setState({refreshCacheAndReload: mockrefreshCacheAndReload})
})
```

Comment: Thank you Zurez for your input. Unfortunately it is not applicable for me, as I am not shallowing <CacheHandler> directly. It is rendered as child component of AdminAppCore component, which I mount. I tried your tip before I mounted AdminnAppCore, but with the result TypeError: this.props.children is not a function. I will add this failed trial to my question